# Increment javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a constructor to alert increament value, how to do this ?

This is what i have

```
var increment = new Increment();

alert(increment); /* 1 */
alert(increment); /* 2 */
alert(increment + increment); /* 7 */
```

Comment: Also, can't be done! In your code `increment` is just a reference, it can't increment whitout calling anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy!

```
function Increment(){
 this.i = 0;   
}

Increment.prototype.toString = function(){
 this.i++;
 return this.i;
}

var increment = new Increment();
```

Comment: I have no idea why this is useful or necessary. `console.log(increment)` won't do anything meaningful, nor will using `increment` in any environment in which is it not trying to be converted into a string.

Comment: well, if you wanted to check how many times `increment` was accessed...it might be useful for weird cases.